# How can I write character ' in Android's strings.xml?

Tags: android

How do I represent the single-quote character (') in strings.xml?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling):

```
<string name="good_example">"This'll work"</string>
<string name="good_example_2">This\'ll also work</string>
```

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Post your `strings.xml` and where and how in the code/layout you use the problematic string.

Comment: This is XML data, not source code _ _! , and it definitely works.

Answer (score 4):

You want to display "This'll work", You should be replace `&#8217;` instead of `'`.
The following code as:

> `<string name="good_example">"This&#8217ll work"</string>`

Comment: This works, but using the single quote HTML code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Character   =    Escaped form(s)

@   =       @

?  =        \?

<  =      <

&   =     &

Single quote (')    = Any of the following:

```
                    &apos;
                    \'
```

Double quote (")    = Any of the following:

```
                 &quot;
                 \"
```

eg.>
without character -- Any Customer's ATM & Debit Card.

correct answer or string--  Any Customer\'s ATM & Debit Card.

Comment: I have asked this query almost 8 years ago! Any how thanks for answering!